# Any way to unsilence?

Tags: game-of-war-fire-age

An alliance member muted another alliance member. Is there any way to unmute them? The game does not make this action clear.

Also, it should be noted that I'm a Rank 4 Admin of my Alliance, so I should have the privilege.

Many thanks.